# Python print decimal in hex formatted to 4 places

Tags: python, printing, format, padding

I have a list of several dozen entries in decimal.

```
CP111 = [  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
[126, 129, 165, 129, 189, 153, 129, 126],  
[126, 255, 219, 255, 195, 231, 255, 126],  
[108, 254, 254, 254, 124, 56, 16, 0],  
[16, 56, 124, 254, 124, 56, 16, 0],  
[56, 124, 56, 254, 254, 124, 56, 124],  
[16, 16, 56, 124, 254, 124, 56, 124],  
[0, 0, 24, 60, 60, 24, 0, 0],  
[255, 255, 231, 195, 195, 231, 255, 255],  
[0, 60, 102, 66, 66, 102, 60, 0],
];
```

I need to convert the decimal to hex, then format the hex to 4 places and print it without the quotes.
This is as close as I have come:

```
CP111 = [  
[0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0],  
[0x3e, 0x41, 0x55, 0x43, 0x55, 0x41, 0x3e, 0x0],  
[0x3e, 0x7f, 0x6b, 0x7d, 0x6b, 0x7f, 0x3e, 0x0],  
[0x38, 0x7c, 0x3e, 0x1f, 0x3e, 0x7c, 0x38, 0x0],  
[0x8, 0x1c, 0x3e, 0x7f, 0x3e, 0x1c, 0x8, 0x0],  
[0x8, 0x1c, 0x29, 0x7f, 0x29, 0x1c, 0x8, 0x0],  
[0x8, 0x1c, 0x3d, 0x7f, 0x3d, 0x1c, 0x8, 0x0],  
[0x0, 0x1c, 0x3e, 0x3e, 0x3e, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0],  
[0xff, 0xe3, 0xc1, 0xc1, 0xc1, 0xe3, 0xff, 0xff],  
[0x0, 0x1c, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0]
];  

for char in CP111:
  print '[{}],'.format(', '.join(hex(x) for x in char))
```

Will get me the printed hex I need but not in the 4 wide padded format

I have tried:

```
print "{0:#0{1}x}".format('[{}]'.format(', '.join(hex(x) for x in font_char)),4)
print '[{}]'.format(', '.join("0x{:04x}".format(hex(x) for x in font_char)))
```

...and several other one line attempts that all end up with syntax errors or ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'

Maybe it's not possible to put it on one line.
I need:

```
CP111 = [  
[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],  
[0x3e, 0x41, 0x55, 0x43, 0x55, 0x41, 0x3e, 0x00],  
[0x3e, 0x7f, 0x6b, 0x7d, 0x6b, 0x7f, 0x3e, 0x00],  
[0x38, 0x7c, 0x3e, 0x1f, 0x3e, 0x7c, 0x38, 0x00],  
[0x08, 0x1c, 0x3e, 0x7f, 0x3e, 0x1c, 0x08, 0x00],  
[0x08, 0x1c, 0x29, 0x7f, 0x29, 0x1c, 0x08, 0x00]  
.....
```

Help please

Comment: `.format(hex(x) for x in font_char)` --> `.format([hex(x) for x in font_char])`

Comment: @ekmcd  I receive this error:      print '[{}],'.format(', '.join("{:04x}".format([hex(x) for x in font_char])))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out in case someone else needs direction:

```
print '[{}],'.format(', '.join('0x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in font_char))
```